# What if we attach a TEG between a freezer and stove?

Tags: power-electronics, energy, peltier, power-generation

I have been thinking about this, that if we attach one part of a thermoelectric generator between a freezer and other part on a stove. This would create a temperature difference and generate electricity. When I will go to cook something on the stove or induction. As the stove gets hot one side will get hotter and other remains cool in the freezer. Is this possible and if it is how long would electricity be generated for.

Comment: You'll spend many times more powering the freezer than you'll save from the TEG's output.

Answer (score 12):

It works, but the way in which a TEG works is to extract energy from the flow of heat like a waterwheel extracts energy from the flow of water. So you'd be cooling the stove, and dumping heat into the freezer. Which increases the temperature of the freezer, causing it to use more energy.

Given how inefficient TEGs are, you'd probably consume 20x more energy in the freezer than generated by the TEG.

Answer (score -3):

It will be too complex to generate enough power, you need a huge amount of thick wires 2 types, junked together on hot side and cold. The efficiency will be completely low

Comment: Too complex to generate enough power _for what?_ OP only asked whether it would generate electricity. Yes. It would generate electricity, but as pjc50's answer says, it would cause the freezer to consume far _more_ electricity as it struggled to keep the cold side of the TEG cold.

Comment: `huge amount of thick wires` for what?

Comment: Guys, strange questions, imagine how TEG is look like. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_generator#/media/File:Thermoelectric_effect.svg
"we attach one part of a thermoelectric generator between a freezer and other part on a stove" - to separate one side from other we need wires, in example above - made from Fe and Cu

Comment: Re, "...how TEG is look like..." Yeah, that's how they would have done it back before [_Peltier devices_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_cooling) were invented. A Peltier device is much easier to work with, but because it is so thin, you might need thick [_heat pipes_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_pipe) to efficiently couple the sides of it to the heat source (kitchen range) and the heat sink (freezer).